# how to open index.php on local network

Tags: networking

i have installed WAMP server on a windows computer and set up a mysql database and php enabled web application. The server is running windows XP.

Now I want to access the index.php file through my Mac connected to the same network. When I browse to the folder and click on the file, it downloads and opens it on the editor instead of the browser. Even when I right click on the file and select open with other, all the browsers are greyed out and not selectable.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: You say you browse to the folder and click on the file. Are you doing this though Finder or using a browser and browsing your server's file/folder tree? You need to access the Windows machine through Safari to check if your server is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the HTML file in the ***File Explorer***.

Web pages served by web servers are supposed to accessed through the **browser** (like Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer).

So, if the name of the server machine (the one running windows XP, in your case) is, say, `windowshost`, then go into the browser and type:

```
http://windowshost
```

Or, maybe, since it is **wamp**:

```
http://windowshost:8080
```

That last part (`:8080`) is the port where the web server is. It really depends on how it is configured.

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusion arising from the fact that the `index.php` file exists in two locations: the 'virtual location` that is provided by the web server, and the actual location on your computer's storage device (whether this is a local or remote storage device).

- When accessed through the server, the PHP is rendered into HTML, so your browser can understand it, and the content-type is explicitly set to HTML.
- When you attempt to open the php file from your file browser, it just looks like a .php file :) So, quite understandably, it opens in your text editor.

In order to see the rendered index.php, you must, in your web browser, go to your Windows' computer's hostname/ip address.

Comment: Since the OP is trying to reach a server on their PC from a Mac they probably would not go to 127.0.0.1 but the hostname of the Windows machine (unless maybe port forwarding is being used).

Comment: @SnapShot: Looks like I fixed that as you were commenting :) Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that Windows Firewall is not blocking port 80

and then from the browser in Mac type : http://[windows-ip-address]/index.php

Comment: This will only work if the Windows machine is serving requests on port 80. It's very likely WAMP is configured to serve on a different port, in which case you have to use http://[windows-ip-address]:[port]/index.php

Comment: you are right except that WAMP is by default configured to serve on port 80 unless is changed after installation.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access through it mac, then first ensure that whether it is accessible on windows if yes, then in that link put your ip address in space of localhost then it will be accessible on mac.If it is still not accessible then put you ip address in mac host file then it will be accessible.